# Remove slash from final string and GET

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

So earlier I was using `http://localhost/profile.php?username=joe` but now I'm using htaccess to make the URL look nice, so this is what it now looks like `http://localhost/joe`. Now here's the issue, before I did this

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
```

And then use it to get the username, but now how would I do it? I've seen other posts, but they seem to use longer and more complex URLs.

I can do this

```
$url = 'http://localhost/joe';
echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
```

And it seems to work fine, but I get a `/` before the actual result so I get `/joe`, and I want `joe`. I've also tried `stripslashes` but that didn't seem to work. So any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). Like this

```
$url = 'http://localhost/joe';
$final =  parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$result = str_replace('/','',$final);
echo $result;
```

[`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) works for backward slashes, not forward slashes

Answer (score 2):

Trim the result on the left site to avoid removing or replacing slashes that are part of the actual value.

```
$result = ltrim($path, '/');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`explode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`array_pop`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php).

```
$url = 'http://localhost/joe';
echo array_pop(explode("/", $url))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a `substr` call should also work:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/joe';
echo substr(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), 1); // joe
```

Answer (score 0):

You can learn about placeholders in routes. Try [this article](http://daylerees.com/codebright/basic-routing)

> Route Parameters
>
> Route parameters can be used to insert placeholders into your route definition. This will effectively create a pattern in which URI segments can be collected and passed to the application’s logic handler.
>
> This might sound a little confusing, but when you see it in action everything will fall into place. Here we go...

```
<?php

// app/routes.php

// routes for the books section
Route::get('/books', function()
{
    return 'Books index.';
});

Route::get('/books/{genre}', function($genre)
{
    return "Books in the {$genre} category.";
});
```

Comment: This a simple example

Comment: I think the step between the code shown in the question and components leading to a full stack framework is not that simple anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Also there is `basename()`

```
echo basename('http://localhost/joe'); //joe
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use this rule or `mod proxy` to rewrite `REQUEST_URI`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}
```

Then you can get your parameter and remove its slashes easily with `trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/')`.